# A strange little number - $6174$.

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

Take a 4 digit number such that it isn't made out the same digit $(1111, 2222, .. . $ etc$)$ Define an operation on such a four digit number by taking the largest number that can be constructed out of these digits and subtracting the smallest four digit number. For example, given the number $2341$, we have,

$4321 - 1234 = 3087$

Repeating this process with the results (by allowing leading zeroes) we get the following numbers:

$8730 - 0378 = 8352$

$8532 - 2358 = 6174$

What's more interesting is that with $6174$ we get

$7641 - 1467 = 6174$

and taking any four digit number we end up with 6174 after at most 7 iterations. A bit of snooping around the internet told me that this number is called the *Kaprekar's constant*. A three digit Kaprekar's contant is the number 495 and there's no such constant for two digit numbers.

My question is, how can we go about proving the above properties algebraically? Specifically, starting with any four digit number we arrive at 6174. I know we can simply test all four digit numbers but the reason I ask is, does there exist a 5 digit Kaprekar's constant? Or an $n$-digit Kaprekar's constant for a given $n$?

Comment: The operation can be viewed as an _operator_ which  is a _contraction_ and leads to a _fixed point_: so fixed point theory is perhaps an appropriate math-tool to model the above phenomenon

Comment: Not too difficult to program 5 digit. In C or C++, given five digit n, the leftmost digit is calculated as: a4 = n / 10000  and the rest of it is rest =  n % 10000. Then a3 = rest / 1000 and rest = rest % 1000. And so on.

Comment: I understand the algorithmic solution. I was just wondering about an algebraic argument. Alecos' fixed point theory is interesting. I'll see if I get anywhere with it.

Comment: Interesting if you found more than one fixpoint. Not possible if the mapping really is a contraction, of course.

Comment: For six digits, both 549945 and 631764 are fixed points, which is interesting. Not everything goes to these fixed points, though. There are cycles, and things go to 0.

Comment: @will: Of course there can be more than one fixpoint. Contractions mappings are only guaranteed to have unique fixpoints under very specific assumptions about the base space and the continuity of the mapping, neither of which applies here.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/495399/28900).

Comment: This isn't a contraction mapping in any reasonable sense of the word that I know of; it's true that $f[\{0000, 9999\}]\subset \{0000, 9999\}$ by definition, but that doesn't hold true for virtually any other interval, and it isn't a contraction under any metric distance function.

Comment: [this](http://kaprekar.sourceforge.net/output/sample.php) article explains kaprekar's constants for higher digit numbers

Comment: @StevenStadnicki:  Each stage has no more values in it than the previous stage.  It is not a distance metric, but a cardinality "metric" that is a non-strict contraction.

Comment: If you are still a fan of $6174$ you may take a look at
[this recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3890249/316749) to an

older Kaprekar question, where the ex. of a, or the, unique fixed point is algebraically proved.

Answer (score 6):

Note: For fun and curiosity I avoid a programming language and stick to algebraic expressions with the intention to feed this through Gnuplot:

The basic operation is
$$
F(n) = F_+(n) - F_-(n)
$$ 
where $F_+$ maps to the maximum digit number and $F_-$ maps to the minimum digit number.

We only consider the case of base $10$ non-negative $4$ digit numbers
$$
(d_3 d_2 d_1 d_0)_{10} = \sum_{k=0}^3 d_k \, 10^k
$$

To provide $F_+$ and $F_-$ we need a way to sort a set of four digits.
This can be done by applying $\min$ and $\max$ functions 
$$
\begin{align}
\min(a, b) &:= \frac{a + b - |a - b|}{2} \\
\max(a, b) &:= \frac{a + b + |a - b|}{2}
\end{align}
$$
like this: We start with calculating intermediate values $s_k$, $t_k$
$$
\begin{matrix}
s_0 = \min(d_0, d_1) \\
s_1 = \max(d_0, d_1) \\
s_2 = \min(d_2, d_3) \\
s_3 = \max(d_2, d_3)
\end{matrix}
\quad\quad
\begin{matrix}
t_0 = \min(s_0, s_2) \\
t_1 = \max(s_0, s_2) \\
t_2 = \min(s_1, s_3) \\
t_3 = \max(s_1, s_3)
\end{matrix}
$$
and then get
$$
d^+_0 = t_0 \quad\quad
d^-_0 = t_3 \\
d^+_1 = \min(t_1, t_2) \quad\quad
d^-_1 = \max(t_1, t_2) \\
d^+_2 = \max(t_1, t_2) \quad\quad
d^-_2 = \min(t_1, t_2) \\
d^+_3 = t_3 \quad\quad
d^-_3 = t_0
$$
where $d^+_k$ are the digits sorted to maximize and $d^-_k$ are the digits sorted to minimize. One can visualize this as a sorting network

```
  d0
    \                                
     \ min: s0 --> min: t0 ----> dp0 dm3
     / max: s1   ^ max: t1
    /        \  /        \
  d1          \/          \ min: dp1 dm2
  d2          /\          / max: dp2 dm1
    \        /  \        /
     \ min: s2   v min: t2
     / max: s3 --> max: t3 ----> dp3 dm0
    /
  d3
```

For example
$$
\begin{align}
d^-_2 
&= \min(t_1, t_2) \\
&= \min(\max(s_0, s_2), \min(s_1, s_3)) \\
&= \min(\max(\min(d_0, d_1), \min(d_2, d_3)), \min(\max(d_0, d_1), \max(d_2, d_3)))
\end{align}
$$
which is a complicated term but otherwise still a function of the $d_k$.

Then we need a way to extract the $k$-th digit:
$$
\pi^{(k)}\left( (d_3 d_2 d_1 d_0)_{10} \right) = d_k
$$
this can be done by the usual
$$
\pi^{(3)}(n) = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{1000} \right\rfloor \\
\pi^{(2)}(n) = \left\lfloor \frac{n - 1000\, \pi^{(3)}(n)}{100} \right\rfloor \\
\pi^{(1)}(n) = \left\lfloor \frac{n - 1000\, \pi^{(3)}(n) - 100\, \pi^{(2)}(n)}{10} \right\rfloor \\
\pi^{(0)}(n) = n - 1000\, \pi^{(3)}(n) - 100\, \pi^{(2)}(n) - 10\, \pi^{(1)}(n)
$$
Rewriting this for Gnuplot gives:

```
min(a,b) = (a + b - abs(a - b))/2.0
max(a,b) = (a + b + abs(a - b))/2.0
dp0(d0,d1,d2,d3) = min(min(d0,d1),min(d2, d3))
dp1(d0,d1,d2,d3) = min(max(min(d0,d1),min(d2,d3)),
                       min(max(d0,d1),max(d2,d3)))
dp2(d0,d1,d2,d3) = max(max(min(d0,d1),min(d2,d3)),
                       min(max(d0,d1),max(d2,d3)))
dp3(d0,d1,d2,d3) = max(max(d0,d1),max(d2, d3))
pi3(n) = floor(n / 1000.0)
pi2(n) = floor((n-1000*pi3(n))/ 100.0)
pi1(n) = floor((n-1000*pi3(n)-100*pi2(n))/ 10.0)
pi0(n) = n-1000*pi3(n)-100*pi2(n)-10*pi1(n)
fp(n) =      dp0(pi0(n),pi1(n),pi2(n),pi3(n)) +
          10*dp1(pi0(n),pi1(n),pi2(n),pi3(n)) + 
         100*dp2(pi0(n),pi1(n),pi2(n),pi3(n)) +
        1000*dp3(pi0(n),pi1(n),pi2(n),pi3(n))
dm0(d0, d1, d2, d3) = dp3(d0,d1,d2,d3)
dm1(d0, d1, d2, d3) = dp2(d0,d1,d2,d3)
dm2(d0, d1, d2, d3) = dp1(d0,d1,d2,d3)
dm3(d0, d1, d2, d3) = dp0(d0,d1,d2,d3)
fm(n) =      dm0(pi0(n),pi1(n),pi2(n),pi3(n)) +
          10*dm1(pi0(n),pi1(n),pi2(n),pi3(n)) + 
         100*dm2(pi0(n),pi1(n),pi2(n),pi3(n)) +
        1000*dm3(pi0(n),pi1(n),pi2(n),pi3(n))
f(x) = fp(x) - fm(x)
```

This works quite nice:

```
gnuplot> print fp(3284), fm(3284)
8432.0 2348.0
```

But it turns out that using the graphics is not precise enough to identify fixed points.

In the end one needs a computer programm to check all numbers $n \in \{ 0, \ldots, 9999 \}$ for a proper fixed point from $\mathbb{N}^2$.

[image: Graph with "set samples = 10000"]

Note: The $\mbox{equ}$ function was used to set the arguments with repeated digits to zero.

```
eq(d0,d1,d2,d3) = (d0 == d1) ? 0 : (d0 == d2) ? 0 : (d0 == d3) ? 0 : 
                  (d1 == d2) ? 0 : (d1 == d3) ? 0 : (d2 == d3) ? 0 : 1
equ(n) = eq(pi0(n),pi1(n),pi2(n),pi3(n))
```

Update: Maybe one can do it better, the calculation precision is good enough:

```
gnuplot> print fp(6174), fm(6174), f(6174)
7641.0 1467.0 6174.0  # <- fixed point!
gnuplot> print fp(6173), fm(6173), f(6173)
7631.0 1367.0 6264.0
gnuplot> print fp(6175), fm(6175), f(6175)
7651.0 1567.0 6084.0
```

Update: This seems to work:

```
gnuplot> set samples 10000
gnuplot> plot [0:9999] [0:1] abs(f(x)*equ(x) - x) < 0.1
```

[image: filtered plot]

Note: The algebraic expressions I used made analysis not easier, the terms are too unwieldy to give the insight to determine the fixed points. It boiled down to to trying out every argument and checking the function value via a computer.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have a partial solution for your question. With some additional simple calculations you can obtain a complete algebraic solution. I would like to start with two and three digit numbers. It will help you to understand my solution.

1. Take a two digit number $ab=10a+b.$ Without loss of generality assume that $a>b.$ Then $$ab-ba=9(a-b)$$ Repeated use of your algorithm on this number goes to the cycle of multiples of $9$ between $9$ and $90.$
2. Take a three digit number $abc$ and with out loss of generality assume that $a \ge b \ge c$ and $a\not= c.$ Then suppose $$abc-cba=99(a-c)=ABC$$ Note that $A\not=9, \,\,\ B=(b-1)+10-b=9$ and $ABC$ can  be divide by $9$ and $11$ respectively. Hence $A+C=9.$ Therefore $ABC$ should be one of the number in the set $$\{198, 297, 396, 495, 594, 693, 792, 891\}$$ Repeted using your algorithm on any of this number will end up at the $495.$
3. Take a four digit number $abcd$ and as in the previous steps without loss of generality assume that $a\ge b\ge c\ge d$ and $a\not= d.$ Also suppose $$abcd-dcba=999(a-d)+90(b-c)=ABCD.$$ Note that $$A\not=9\\ D=10-a+d \\ C=(c-1)+10-b=9-b+c$$

If $b=c$ then $$B=(b-1)+10-c=9+b-c\\ A=-1+a-d.$$ This implies $B+C=18,\,\ A+C=9.$
Therefore $B=C=9$ and $(A,C)\in\{(0,9),(1,8),(2,7),(3,6),(4,5),(5,4),(6,3),(7,2).(8,1),(9,0)\}$

If $b>c$ then $$B=-1+b-c\\ A=a-d.$$ This implies $B+C=8,\,\ A+C=10.$
Therefore $(B,C)\in \{(0,8),(1,7), ...,(8,0)$ and $(A,C)\in\{(1,9),(2,8), ...,(9,1)\}$

Here you have $91$ possible values for $ABCD.$ I think you can continue from here. Apply your algorithm on all of them. If your $abcd$ of the form $a=b=c$ or $b=c=d,$ then you will end up with $0.$ Otherwise you will end up with $6174.$